# How to remove certain types of code from loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop, append

Hi there can someone please help with something fairly simple. I have the following code to take in names until the name john or John is entered. Then it will print a string listing the incorrect names entered. The problem I am having is its asking the user to enter a name again after printing the string.
any help would be great.

my code is as follows:

```
user_input=""
c = []
while user_input != "John" or user_input != "john":
    a = (input("Please enter your name:"))
    b = c.append(a)
    if a == "John" or a == "john":
        print ("Incorrect names are:" + str(c[0:-1]))
```

Thank you

Comment: `while user_input != "John" or user_input != "john"` should be `while user_input != "John" and user_input != "john"`. Every string is different to one **or** the other, since it can't equal both of them.

Comment: You are never changing `user_input` so it is always `""` and always `!= "John"`

Comment: The mix-up with the condition could be easily avoided by using `while user_input.lower() != "john":`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never update `user_input`, and you have twice the same condition, you may ask until you have john, then print, also `b` is useless as `append` modify the current list :

```
user_input=""
wrong = []

while user_input != "John" and user_input != "john": # and use an 'and'
    user_input = input("Please enter your name:")
    wrong.append(user_input )

print ("Incorrect names are:", c[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just break it!

```
user_input=""
c = []
while user_input != "John" or user_input != "john":
  a = (input("Please enter your name:"))
  b = c.append(a)
  if a == "John" or a == "john":
      print ("Incorrect names are:" + str(c[0:-1]))
      break
```